# How to bake an object with distinct faces

Tags: texturing, shaders, faces, shader-nodes

[image]I just finished following a tutorial to make this stylized shader for a tree. However I need to export this tree to another program, the issue is, that the "leaves" are separated in different planes. How can I export this texture as it is in the image to another program?

Comment: So will the exported object still have separate leaves?

Comment: yes they will all be exported in the same object, but they will be different